# how to keep part of a string using vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have following cell values

```
158,4437
159,5656
160,8521
```

Now I want to keep the cell values till two positions after the ,

like

```
158,44
159,56
160,85
```

Can anyone please help me with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
Const sTest = "158,4437"
Dim sOutput : sOutput = Left(sTest, InStr(sTest, ",")+2)
```